# Delete text in EditText while holding down Delete key using a custom TextWatcher

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I'm using a custom `TextWatcher` in an `EditText` widget, and this makes it impossible to use both the onscreen dictionary and continuously deleting text while holding down the text key on the virtual keyboard.

I don't care about the dictionary, but I'd really like being able to just hold down the delete key to delete large bits of text. It works just fine without the `TextWatcher`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Same problem here, can you remember how did you solve ?